# Session.Abandon() does not abandon the session straight away

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

In my ASP.NET web app I call `Session.Abandon()` in `Page_Load()`. I would expect this would abandon the session straight away and the next time I reference the `HttpContext.Current.Session` a new session should be created. However, putting breakpoints on the `Session_End` and `Session_Start` handlers in Global.asax indicates that these aren't called until the page has finished rendering.

So two questions:

1) Why?

2) How can I continue to use `HttpContext.Current.Session` within a page lifecycle once Session.Abandon() has been called.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx

Look at the remarks section on the linked page.
Looks like the session objects are only queued for deletion, and not deleted until the code finishes running.

Comment: Thanks Elad. So it would seem that the answer to my second question is that it is not a good idea to continue using the session object in the current page lifecycle once Session.Abandon() has been called as it won't be hanging around once the page has rendered.

Comment: I think it will be available on the current page, but not on subsequent pages and/or if the page is refreshed/goes through another postback. In any case, if you call session.abandon, logid dictates that you have no more use for it anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

This was my solution:

```
private void PurgeSession()
{
    try
    {
        Session.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }

    try
    {
        Session.Abandon();
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }

    try
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }

    try
    {
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId") 
                                {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)});
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }
}
```

This is effectively the orbital bombardment option.

Some information sourced from: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1395-how-to-avoid-the-session-fixation-vulnerability-in-aspnet-.aspx

Comment: I also understand there's some way to get "ASP.NET_SessionId" from the web.config to support if people changed their session cookie name, but I didn't care to dig that out since I use the default names.

Answer (score 2):

Session.Abandon() actually waits until the page has been rendered.